# onCreateView holder is getting called Multiple times and view is not getting updated

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, data-binding, android-livedata

The problem is When data refreshes view is not getting updated.
My findings- 
 1. onCreateview is getting called multiple times, so multiple binder objects are there 
 2. I checked the list, updated list is reaching to the adapter 
 3. Data inserted in the db is correct. 
 4. I have atttached all the code snippets related to this 
 5. I have used sqaureup library for calendar

```
 package com.universal.best.habittracker.view

    import android.content.Context
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import `androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil`
    import androidx.fragment.app.*
    import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.R


    import com.universal.best.habittracker.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.repository.entity.ActivityEntityClass
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.view.adapter.ActivityListAdapter
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.view.adapter.ActivityStatusAdapter
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.viewmodel.MainAcitivityViewModelProvider
    import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
    import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
    import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
    import java.util.*

    class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity(),
        AddActivityFinishInterface, ActivityAdapterEventrack {

        lateinit private var mainActivityDataBinding: ActivityMainBinding
        lateinit private var viewModel: MainAcitivityViewModelProvider;
        val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager;

       val tag:String="MainActivity"

        companion object {
            var newFragment: DialogFragment? = null
            internal lateinit var context: Context
            internal lateinit var mainActivityContext: Context

            fun setContext(con: Context, mainActivityContextt: Context) {
                context = con
                mainActivityContext = mainActivityContextt
            }

        }


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            mainActivityDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
                this,
                R.layout.activity_main
            );


            setContext(
                applicationContext, this
            );
            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainAcitivityViewModelProvider::class.java)
            var handleCLick =
                HandleCLick(
                    this,
                    fragmentManager, viewModel,
                    this
                );

            mainActivityDataBinding.clickHandler = handleCLick;
            Log.d(tag,"Adapter created--")
            var listAdapter = ActivityListAdapter(this);
            Log.d(tag,"Adapter created with Hashcode--"+listAdapter.hashCode())
            mainActivityDataBinding.listAdapter = listAdapter;
            mainActivityDataBinding.recyclerView.adapter=  listAdapter
            mainActivityDataBinding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL ,false)
            var statusAdapter = ActivityStatusAdapter();

            mainActivityDataBinding.statusAdaptor = statusAdapter
            mainActivityDataBinding.bottomRecylerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

            viewModel.retreiveFromDb()
                .observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { list ->
                    list?.let {
                        listAdapter.setAdapterData(list)
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        statusAdapter.setAdapter(list)
                        statusAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                })

           viewModel.getSaveres()?.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { viewModel.retreiveFromDb()
               .observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { list ->
                   list?.let {


                       listAdapter.setAdapterData(list)
                       listAdapter.ListChangedSoCallNotify()
                       statusAdapter.clear()
                       statusAdapter.setAdapter(list)
                       statusAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                   }
               })
           })

        }

        class HandleCLick(
            val context: Context,
            val fragmentManager: FragmentManager, val viewmodel: MainAcitivityViewModelProvider,

            val addActivityFinishInterface: AddActivityFinishInterface
        ) {

            fun onClick(view: View) {
                when (view.id) {
                    R.id.imageView -> {
                        newFragment =
                            AddActivityDialogueFragment(
                                addActivityFinishInterface
                            )
                        newFragment?.show(fragmentManager, "dialog")
                    };

                    else -> {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    };

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        override fun clickHandler(activtyName: String, list: ArrayList<Date>?) {
            Toast.makeText(this, activtyName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            newFragment?.dismiss()
            var len: Int = list?.size ?: 0
            when {
                len == 1 -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Valid date range  selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    list?.let {
                        viewModel.saveintoDB(activtyName, list.get(0), list.get(len - 1), "0") }
                }
                else -> Toast.makeText(this, "Valid date range  not selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()

            }
        }

        @Override
        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            viewModel.close();
        }

        override fun deleteTriggered(model: ActivityEntityClass) {

            viewModel.deleteEntityFromDB(model)
        }

        override fun viewChartTriggered() {

        }

        override fun imageCharTriggered() {

        }


    Above is my mainActivity 



    myAdapterClass

    package com.universal.best.habittracker.view.adapter

    import android.app.AlertDialog
    import android.content.DialogInterface
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.R
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.databinding.TopActivitiesItemLayoutBinding
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.repository.entity.ActivityEntityClass
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.view.ActivityAdapterEventrack
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.view.MainActivity
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.view.MainActivity.Companion.context
    import com.universal.best.habittracker.view.MainActivity.Companion.mainActivityContext


    class ActivityListAdapter(var adaptercallBackInterface: ActivityAdapterEventrack) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
        var list: List<ActivityEntityClass>? = null
        val tag: String = "ActivityListAdapter"
        lateinit var myViewHolder: MyViewHolder
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

           val inflater =LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val databinder = TopActivitiesItemLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater);
            Log.d(tag, "onCreate dataBinder--" + databinder.hashCode());
            myViewHolder = MyViewHolder(databinder);
            Log.d(tag, "onCreate viewholder--" + myViewHolder.hashCode());
            var Handler = MyClickHandler(adaptercallBackInterface)
            databinder.myclickHanlder = Handler
            return myViewHolder;
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list?.size ?: 0
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            myViewHolder.bindData(list, position);

        }

        override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
            return position
        }

        fun setAdapterData(list: List<ActivityEntityClass>?) {
            this.list = list

        }

        class MyViewHolder( databinder: TopActivitiesItemLayoutBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(databinder.root) {
            val databinderr: TopActivitiesItemLayoutBinding = databinder

            fun bindData(
                list: List<ActivityEntityClass>?,
                i: Int
            ) {
                databinderr.model = list?.get(i)
                databinderr.executePendingBindings()

            }
        }

        class MyClickHandler(var eventrack: ActivityAdapterEventrack) {
            fun onclick(view: View, entityClass: ActivityEntityClass) {
                when (view.id) {
                    R.id.imageView2 -> {
                        //open dialogbox and on yes delete it from db..
                        val dialogClickListener =
                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                                when (which) {
                                    DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE -> {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            MainActivity.mainActivityContext,
                                            "Activity name is ${entityClass.activityName}",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                        ).show()
                                        eventrack.deleteTriggered(entityClass)
                                    }
                                    DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE -> {
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        var builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivityContext)

                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this activity?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show()
                    }
                    R.id.imageView4 -> {
                        //open new actiivty with intent
                    }


                }
            }


        }

        fun ListChangedSoCallNotify() {
            notifyDataSetChanged()


        }


    }


    mainActivty layout
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>

            <variable
                    name="clickHandler"
                    type="com.universal.best.habittracker.view.MainActivity.HandleCLick" />

            <variable
                    name="listAdapter"
                    type="com.universal.best.habittracker.view.adapter.ActivityListAdapter" />

            <variable
                    name="statusAdaptor"
                    type="com.universal.best.habittracker.view.adapter.ActivityStatusAdapter" />


        </data>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/homepage_bg"
                tools:context=".view.Activity.MainActivity">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Add New Habit to Track"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_add"
                    android:onClick="@{(view)->clickHandler.onClick(view)}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.945"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.738" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/notext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="23dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                    tools:text="You are not tracking any habbit" />


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/top_activities_item_layout" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:text="Habbit Status" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/bottomRecylerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:adapter="@{statusAdaptor}"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/habit_staus_item" />

            <TextView
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"

                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Select Other date"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.588"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </layout>


    adapter layout

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>

            <variable
                    name="model"
                    type="com.universal.best.habittracker.repository.entity.ActivityEntityClass" />

            <variable
                    name="myclickHanlder"
                    type="com.universal.best.habittracker.view.adapter.ActivityListAdapter.MyClickHandler" />

        </data>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/itemview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Yoga"
                    android:layout_width="123dp"
                    android:layout_height="174dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/activity_item_background_color"
                    android:fontFamily="monospace"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@{model.activityName}"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:text="Yoga" />

            <ImageView
                    android:onClick="@{(view)->myclickHanlder.onclick(view,model)}"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="144dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Yoga"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.294"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Yoga"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Yoga"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/deleete" />

            <ImageView

                    android:onClick="@{(view)->myclickHanlder.onclick(view,model)}"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_45sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Yoga"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Yoga"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Yoga"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/chart" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

**`DataBindingUtil.setContentView()`** Utility class to create **[ViewDataBinding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding)** from layouts.

> Base class for generated data binding classes. If possible, the
>   generated binding should be instantiated using one of its generated
>   static bind or inflate methods. If the specific binding is unknown,
>   bind(View) or inflate(LayoutInflater, int, ViewGroup, boolean) should
>   be used.

1. **onCreateview()** is getting called multiple times

You are using DataBinding. So kindly remove below.

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

**Finally**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            mainActivityDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
                this,
                R.layout.activity_main
            );
```

Comment: Ohhh god....How did I miss that. Thanks for the reply. This might be issue that why multiple objects are getting created . I will check and accept your ans.

Comment: Again onCreateView of the adapter is getting called multiple times resulting in multiple instances of viewholder

Comment: this is the repo -- https://github.com/Ashish-create/LearnKotin

Comment: @ashishyadav see https://www.journaldev.com/23989/android-recyclerview-data-binding

Comment: https://blog.untitledkingdom.com/refactoring-recyclerview-adapter-to-data-binding-5631f239095f

Comment: need to rectify adapter section.

Comment: Got stuck here. A much needed help